# How to add additional option to a select tag with set of ids to be passed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a select tag which has doc_category name and its id passing to controller, along with this there is also a website's doc_id  passing inside option_for_select. now i have to add all docs to that list which should hold ids of all docs and also it should also send the website's doc_id and the name should be "All docs".

```
given code 
td= select_tag "doc_id", options_for_select((DocumentCategory.order_name.pluck(:name, :id)), params[:doc_id]), class: 'form-control'  


I tried with
td= select_tag "doc_id", options_for_select(DocumentCategory.order_name.pluck(:name, :id)+(['All Docs',DocumentCategory.all.pluck(:id)]), params[:doc_ids]), class: 'form-control'
```

this code is working for download operation in the controller there is a download action which validates the existence of  doc_category.id  and website. doc_category_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your right.

- First of all it is not a good practice to call models from views. Create a helper for this.
- the second - it is not good to pass many ids as a single value for "All docs" option.
- Do not call method `all` if you have many(>1000) records in `DocumentCategory` table. Use `find_each` instead. You can also call do direct call of `pluck` on models `DocumentCategory.pluck(:name, :id)`.

I'd recommend:

helper:

```
def options_for_categories
  options = DocumentCategory.order_name.pluck(:name, :id)
  options << ['All Docs', 'all']
  # you can define your own logic for selected value.
  selected = params[:doc_id].to_i > 0 ? params[:doc_id] : 'all' 
  options_for_select(options, selected)
end
```

view:

```
%td= select_tag "doc_id", options_for_categories, class: 'form-control'
```

controller:

```
def your_action
  # .. your logic ..
  if params[:doc_id] == 'all'
    # do something here
  end
end
```